# Raspberry Pi wiring simple LED

Tags: led, raspberry-pi

I'm completely new to hardware in general. I just got a raspberry pi and was messing around trying to get an LED to light up.

I have everything wired like the picture below. I am using a 330ohm resister, which I believe is bigger therefore ok then what is required.

[image]

also (sorry this is my first time using any program to draw a circuit)

[image]

The program runs successfully, but no light comes on. I know the LED is good as I've tested it on the arduino. Anybody care to explain my wiring fault?

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(11, True)
```

---

Changing to GPIO pin 0 results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(0, GPIO.OUT)
RPi.GPIO.InvalidChannelException: The channel sent is invalid on a Raspberry Pi
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the GPIO is actually at 3.3V? (or whatever the Rpi uses) Also, a schematic would be better than the picture, it's difficult to see what's connected to what.

Comment: Are you sere you don't need to add a pull-up resistor? Try connecting the resistor to +5V and invert the diode.

Comment: That looks okay (I'm assuming the anode of the LED actually connects to the GPIO in the bottom diagram) Did you test the pin is set to a high (e.g. 3.3V) level when you run your program? Is the LED the right way round?

Comment: What color is the LED?

Answer (score 3):

Try reversing the led. The longer lead should be connected to the gpio pin and not ground. Also are you using the correct pin? Some are disabled

Answer (score 3):

If your Fritzing diagram is correct, you've connected your LED to the S_CLK pin of the SPI bus, which is also known as pin 11. Try using one of the general purpose pins (GPIO0-7) rather than the special-purpose pins.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the **Pin 4** (the bottom row, 4th pin, it is marked as #4 in Fritzing). Then change your program to:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Note the GPIO.BCM here, and not GPIO.BOARD
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(4, True)
```

And run your program with "sudo", like this: `sudo python ./my_prog.py`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Broadcom GPIO numbering for the channel but specified `GPIO.BOARD` as the numbering mode. Either change the numbering mode to `GPIO.BCM` or use 23 as the channel number.